# You are not authorized for this operation. Invalid access token DialogFlow v2

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I am trying to use DialogFlow v2 endpoint but for some reason I am getting not authorized message, eventhou I am able to generate access token using the following command:

Initially I am running this to authorize the service for my local machine to be able to authorize to the service: `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=<service-account-key-file.json>` then I get access token by following command: `gcloud auth print-access-token` and this access token I am attaching on the following code:

```
fetch(configs.baseUrl + "query?v=20150910", {
    body: JSON.stringify({query: text, lang: "en", sessionId: "somerandomthing"}),
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
    },
    method: 'POST',
})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data.result.fulfillment.speech);
        return data.result.fulfillment.speech;
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

I dont know if this is the right way to achieve a communication with DialogFlow V2? 
Please if you could let me know what I am doing wrong and why I it says I am not authorised since I am authorizing by the above commands and been able to get access token!

Edit:

After few changes my code finally looks like this:

```
fetch("https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2beta1/projects/xxx/agent/sessions/xxx/:detectIntent", {
        body: JSON.stringify({queryInput: "Hello"}),
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            "Authorization": "Bearer xxxx",
        },
        method: 'POST',
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.result.fulfillment.speech);
            return data.result.fulfillment.speech;
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

and the new error message I get is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid value at 'query_input' (type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.QueryInput), \"Hello\"",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "query_input",
            "description": "Invalid value at 'query_input' (type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.QueryInput), \"Saanko yhteystiedot?\""
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show the `baseUrl` you're using, but that looks like the V1 API rather than the V2 API. You should [migrate your code to V2](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v1-v2-migration-guide-api#rest_api_migration).

Keep in mind, also, that the access token expires, so you will need to generate a new one periodically. You cannot request a "long lived" token (this is considered insecure), but should have your code call `gcloud auth print-access-token` (or use a library to do the same thing) before the previous one expires.

**Update** based on your code once you've moved it to V2:

The `queryInput` parameter doesn't take a string directly. It must be set to a [QueryInput object](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/QueryInput). This is an enum, so can only have one of the fields specified set. It looks like you want the `text` field which requires a [TextInput object](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/QueryInput#TextInput).

So your `body` parameter might be setup something like this:

```
var body = {
  queryInput: {
    text: {
      text: "Hello",
      language: "en-US"
    }
  }
};
var bodyStr = JSON.stringify(body);
```

and then set in your `request()` options.

Comment: I am using thisL https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2beta1/projects/lakiklinikka/agent/intentsas base url, seems working but no problem with auth but its not detecting the intent and respons corrosponding answer from my dialogflow, it says "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"query_input\" at 'intent': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"language_code\" at 'intent': Cannot find field.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",

Also how do I get a longer live access token, or how do I refresh it automatically?

Comment: basically I am not able to find which url I should be using for detecting the intent

Comment: can you provide me a code sample of how would a url and post body should look like for v2? For some reason I am all confused on this!

Comment: i tried this url: https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2beta1/{session=projects/*/agent/sessions/*}:detectIntent and just replaced with my own projectid and session id, but it returns 404

Comment: my final url looks like: "https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2beta1/detectIntent?session=projects/xxx/agent/sessions/xxx" still get 404, so it means I am not constructing correct http post request. can you show me how would this url would look like?

Comment: ok this url seems to work: https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2beta1/projects/yyy/agent/sessions/xxxx/:detectIntent but i get Invalid arguments

Comment: currently I only pass  body: JSON.stringify({queryInput: text}), but then I get Invalid value at 'query_input' (type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.QueryInput), \"Hello\"

Comment: Please don't provide examples in the comments - they're very difficult to read. Update your question with any additional information and leave a note in the comment that you've done so.

Comment: I updated my question please see Edit section bottom!

Comment: this is working :)  I just had to change language key to language_code... thanx, do u mind also suggesting me with the access token how do I refresh it periodically? or can I get a access token that expires for example after 1 year?

Comment: updated that part of my answer to address... but further discussion about it would probably merit a separate SO question and longer answer.

Comment: thnx I will propbably make a separate question for the access token thing! thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

```
Because you have put wrong URL in your project.
Open below image and see which URL use for posturl in your project
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ym9n.png