# difficulty in getting authorization from dialogflow api v1. Getting error "Request failed with status code 401"

Tags: node.js, axios, dialogflow-es

im using axios to connect my bot to dialog-flow API v1.it is returning a 401 error saying unauthorized?

i have all ready set up the headers and the data types to application/json.

```
var axios =require('axios');
var URL ='https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/';

let config = {
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + '4c52dfb9db61xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        "Content-Type": "application/json"

    }
  }
var bodyParameters = {
    "queryInput": { "text":
     { } 
    },
    "query": "hi hello",
    "languageCode": "en",
    "sessionId": "12345",
    "timezone": "xxxxx"
};


axios.get(URL,bodyParameters, config)
.then(function(res){
    console.log(res.data);

}).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);

});
```

is there some error in authorization?

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50638542/you-are-not-authorized-for-this-operation-invalid-access-token-dialogflow-v2). It might help you

Comment: thanks i finally did it using node-fetch. **for anyone else interested  here is my code  **  `  fetch(URL+"query?v=20150910", {
    body: JSON.stringify({query: "new york city", lang: "en", sessionId: "12345"}),
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
    },
    method: 'POST',
})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data.result.fulfillment.speech);
        return data.result.fulfillment.speech;
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))`

Answer (score 1):

after searching i found that it was much easy to do API request using node-fetch

```
fetch(URL+"query?v=20150910", {
    body: JSON.stringify({query: "new york city", lang: "en", sessionId: "12345"}),
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
    },
    method: 'POST',
})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data.result.fulfillment.speech);
        return data.result.fulfillment.speech;
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
```